# Why is the segmentation fault happening when I try to copy *str = *tmp

Tags: c

This code replaced the space with `%20` and the char array is supposed to contain enough spaces to add `%20`.

Can you please help me understand why I get a segfault at `*str = *tmp; // segfault at this location..`?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


char* encodeSpace(char* str) {
    char *orig = str;
    while (*str++);

     str--;
     char *tmp = --str;
     while (*tmp-- == ' ');
     tmp++;
     while (tmp != orig) {
        while(*tmp != ' ' && tmp != orig) {

        *str = *tmp; // segfault at this location.. 
         tmp--;
         str--;
        }
        *str-- = '0';
        *str-- = '2';
        *str-- = '%';
        tmp--;
     }
     return tmp;
}

main()
{
   printf("output is %s", encodeSpace("My Name is john         "));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Initial primary problem

You get a segmentation fault because you attempt to modify a string literal (the argument to the function).

String literals are normally in read-only memory and may not legitimately be modified.  An attempt to do so leads to undefined behaviour.  A segmentation fault is a legitimate undefined behaviour.

You would be OK if you wrote:

```
int main(void)
{
    char str[] = "My Name is john         ";
    printf("output is %s", encodeSpace(str));
    return 0;
}
```

or even (using a C99 compound literal):

```
int main(void)
{
    printf("output is %s", encodeSpace((char[]){"My Name is john         "}));
    return 0;
}
```

---

#### Algorithmic Problems

Because you can decrement `tmp` twice in a loop, you aren't guaranteed to recognize when it reaches the `orig` pointer.  This code crashes in the `assert()`:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

static
char *encodeSpace(char *str)
{
    char *orig = str;
    printf("-->> str = %p <<%s>>\n", (void *)str, str);

    while (*str++)
        ;

    str--;
    char *tmp = --str;
    while (*tmp-- == ' ')
        ;
    tmp++;
    printf("tmp = %p <<%s>>\n", (void *)tmp, tmp);
    printf("str = %p <<%s>>\n", (void *)str, str);
    while (tmp != orig)
    {
        while (*tmp != ' ' && tmp != orig)
        {
            printf("--1: tmp = %p <<%s>>; str = %p <<%s>>\n", (void *)tmp, tmp, (void *)str, str);
            *str = *tmp; // segfault at this location..
            tmp--;
            str--;
            printf("--2: tmp = %p <<%s>>; str = %p <<%s>>\n", (void *)tmp, tmp, (void *)str, str);
        }
        //if (tmp != orig)
        //{
        *str-- = '0';
        *str-- = '2';
        *str-- = '%';
        tmp--;
        //}
        printf("--3: tmp = %p <<%s>>; str = %p <<%s>>\n", (void *)tmp, tmp, (void *)str, str);
        assert(tmp >= orig);
    }
    printf("<<-- tmp = <<%s>>\n", tmp);
    return tmp;
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("output is <<%s>>\n", encodeSpace((char[]){"My name is John         "}));
    return 0;
}
```

Remove the comments and it no longer crashes (the second decrement of `tmp` is protected).  But the output isn't quite what you want.

```
-->> str = 0x7fff54cb44c0 <<My name is John         >>
tmp = 0x7fff54cb44ce <<n         >>
str = 0x7fff54cb44d7 << >>
--1: tmp = 0x7fff54cb44ce <<n         >>; str = 0x7fff54cb44d7 << >>
--2: tmp = 0x7fff54cb44cd <<hn        n>>; str = 0x7fff54cb44d6 << n>>
--1: tmp = 0x7fff54cb44cd <<hn        n>>; str = 0x7fff54cb44d6 << n>>
--2: tmp = 0x7fff54cb44cc <<ohn       hn>>; str = 0x7fff54cb44d5 << hn>>
--1: tmp = 0x7fff54cb44cc <<ohn       hn>>; str = 0x7fff54cb44d5 << hn>>
--2: tmp = 0x7fff54cb44cb <<John      ohn>>; str = 0x7fff54cb44d4 << ohn>>
--1: tmp = 0x7fff54cb44cb <<John      ohn>>; str = 0x7fff54cb44d4 << ohn>>
--2: tmp = 0x7fff54cb44ca << John     John>>; str = 0x7fff54cb44d3 << John>>
--3: tmp = 0x7fff54cb44c9 <<s John  %20John>>; str = 0x7fff54cb44d0 << %20John>>
--1: tmp = 0x7fff54cb44c9 <<s John  %20John>>; str = 0x7fff54cb44d0 << %20John>>
--2: tmp = 0x7fff54cb44c8 <<is John s%20John>>; str = 0x7fff54cb44cf << s%20John>>
--1: tmp = 0x7fff54cb44c8 <<is John s%20John>>; str = 0x7fff54cb44cf << s%20John>>
--2: tmp = 0x7fff54cb44c7 << is Johnis%20John>>; str = 0x7fff54cb44ce <<nis%20John>>
--3: tmp = 0x7fff54cb44c6 <<e is J%20is%20John>>; str = 0x7fff54cb44cb <<J%20is%20John>>
--1: tmp = 0x7fff54cb44c6 <<e is J%20is%20John>>; str = 0x7fff54cb44cb <<J%20is%20John>>
--2: tmp = 0x7fff54cb44c5 <<me is e%20is%20John>>; str = 0x7fff54cb44ca << e%20is%20John>>
--1: tmp = 0x7fff54cb44c5 <<me is e%20is%20John>>; str = 0x7fff54cb44ca << e%20is%20John>>
--2: tmp = 0x7fff54cb44c4 <<ame isme%20is%20John>>; str = 0x7fff54cb44c9 <<sme%20is%20John>>
--1: tmp = 0x7fff54cb44c4 <<ame isme%20is%20John>>; str = 0x7fff54cb44c9 <<sme%20is%20John>>
--2: tmp = 0x7fff54cb44c3 <<name iame%20is%20John>>; str = 0x7fff54cb44c8 <<iame%20is%20John>>
--1: tmp = 0x7fff54cb44c3 <<name iame%20is%20John>>; str = 0x7fff54cb44c8 <<iame%20is%20John>>
--2: tmp = 0x7fff54cb44c2 << name name%20is%20John>>; str = 0x7fff54cb44c7 << name%20is%20John>>
--3: tmp = 0x7fff54cb44c1 <<y na%20name%20is%20John>>; str = 0x7fff54cb44c4 <<a%20name%20is%20John>>
--1: tmp = 0x7fff54cb44c1 <<y na%20name%20is%20John>>; str = 0x7fff54cb44c4 <<a%20name%20is%20John>>
--2: tmp = 0x7fff54cb44c0 <<My ny%20name%20is%20John>>; str = 0x7fff54cb44c3 <<ny%20name%20is%20John>>
--3: tmp = 0x7fff54cb44c0 <<My ny%20name%20is%20John>>; str = 0x7fff54cb44c3 <<ny%20name%20is%20John>>
<<-- tmp = <<My ny%20name%20is%20John>>
output is <<My ny%20name%20is%20John>>
```

I think that your algorithm is convoluted because you are trying to do the change in situ.  I couldn't work out how to fix it.  It would be far simpler to pass in an input string (which could be a string literal, and would not need to be blank padded) and an output buffer whose size you specify in the call:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static int encodeSpace(char const *src, char *buffer, size_t buflen)
{
    char *end = buffer + buflen;
    char c;
    char *dst = buffer;

    while ((c = *src++) != '\0' && dst < end)
    {
        if (c != ' ')
            *dst++ = c;
        else if (dst < end - 3)
        {
            *dst++ = '%';
            *dst++ = '2';
            *dst++ = '0';
        }
        else
            return -1;
    }
    *dst = '\0';
    return 0;
}

int main(void)
{
    char buffer[64];

    if (encodeSpace("My name is John", buffer, sizeof(buffer)) == 0)
        printf("output is <<%s>>\n", buffer);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
output is <<My%20name%20is%20John>>
```

Comment: There's still a problem — working on it.  However, I think the residual problem is trampling out of bounds rather than writing to read-only memory.

Comment: Do a dry run - what happens when you try to insert the %20 at the space after My?  You're going to overshoot past the start of the string.

Answer (score 0):

@Jonathan Leffler's solution is perfect.

I have tried to fix the original algorithm but it looks hard to change in origin char buffer because `%20` takes three char position, if the `space` char is not enough, code still goes wrong.

code following works well iff space is enough.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


char* encodeSpace(char* str) {
    char *orig = str;
    while (*str++);

     str--;
     char *tmp = --str;
     while (*tmp == ' ') tmp--;
     tmp++;
     while (tmp != orig) {
        while(*tmp != ' ') {
         *str = *tmp;
         str--;
         if (tmp == orig)
            break;
         else
           tmp--;
        }
        if (*tmp == ' ') {
          *str-- = '0';
          *str-- = '2';
          *str-- = '%';
          while (*tmp == ' ') tmp--;
        } 
     }
     return ++str;
}

int main()
{

    char str[] = "My Name is john            ";
   printf("output is %s\n", encodeSpace(str));
   return 0;
}
```